# Cart data aggregation in javascript

Tags: javascript, payload

I need to write a data aggregation method for my cart, but i'm stuck. I have const payload with empty array and loop that will run getData() method for every product in my cart and push the result to my empty array. Also i need my getData() method, that will return for me id, amount, price and priceSingel. All of those we got in CarProduct constructor. I am still new and i do get stuck sometimes with the basics.

```
const payload = {
        products: [],
        address: 'test',
        totalPrice: thisCart.totalPrice,
      };

      for(let product of thisCart.products) {
        product.getData();
      }
      payload.products.push(product);
```

```
  /* get data for .getData */
    getData() {
      return id;
      return amount;
      return price;
      return priceSingle;
      return params;
    }
```

```
/* part of cart product constructor */
class CartProduct {
    constructor (menuProduct, element) {
      const thisCartProduct = this;

      thisCartProduct.id = menuProduct.id;
      thisCartProduct.name = menuProduct.name;
      thisCartProduct.price = menuProduct.price;
      thisCartProduct.priceSingle =menuProduct.priceSingle;
      thisCartProduct.amount = menuProduct.amount;
```

Comment: for more code please check https://github.com/shivetay/kodilla_pizza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to help you with this little view of your code.

However, some problems that you can resolve:

A method can't have more than ONE effective return, the first encountered is used.
So for your `getData()`, you should return an object:

```
getData() {
  return { // this is a shortcut where key is named like the variable
    id,
    amount,
    price,
    priceSingle,
    params
  }
}
```

I don't know what's your `params` here.

Secondly, add data to your array while you loop, not after (and here you don't use the `getData()` return)

```
for(let product of thisCart.products) {
  payload.products.push(product.getData());
}
```

Comment: Doubidou thanks, you pushed me a bit :) got it working